# Installation of libjpeg not found

Tags: macos, libjpeg

I'm new to macOS, and I'm having trouble using the library libjpeg.

After installing with brew install jpeg, I even tried reinstalling.

```
joshbone@Joshs-Mac-mini ~ % brew reinstall jpeg
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/jpeg-9d.arm64_big_sur.bottl
Already downloaded: /Users/joshbone/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/12e480d7337641afc99230ff2b626197e3206ea378eef8ccbb8b11f587afe7f4--jpeg-9d.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
==> Reinstalling jpeg 
==> Pouring jpeg-9d.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jpeg/9d: 21 files, 1001.2KB
```

Then I try to see if I can find the library, I type the following command in terminal: "gcc -ljpeg". This gives output below:

```
ld: library not found for -ljpeg
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why can't it find the library? And what can I do to fix the installation? Am I even using these terminal commands correctly?

EDIT: I managed to find the symlink (.dylib) under /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jpeg/9d/lib. But when I ran gcc -ljpeg -L /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jpeg/9d/lib/, I get the following error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Try adding `-L /usr/local/lib`

Answer (score 5):

> Why can't it find the library?

It either doesn't exist or isn't in the include path.

> And what can I do to fix the installation?

Use the `-v` flag as gcc suggests (`gcc -ljpeg -v`). You'll see a `-L` flag and that will tell you where it's looking for library files (the include path). In my case it's `-L/usr/local/lib` and if I look in that directory for "jpeg" (`ls /usr/local/lib/ | grep jpeg`) I see `libjpeg.dylib` is there.

brew by default installs to `/usr/local/Cellar` on Intel or `/opt/homebrew` on ARM (hereby referred to as `<prefix>`). The file `<prefix>/jpeg/9d/lib/libjpeg.dylib` should exist and brew should have created `/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.dylib` as a symlink to the installed version. Potentially brew isn't creating that symlink like it's supposed to. Running `brew doctor` may offer some insight or you could manually create that symlink but without knowing more you may run into this issue with other libraries.

Another option is to tell gcc to look in the path brew says it installed libjpeg to: `gcc -v -ljpeg -L <prefix>/jpeg/9d/lib/`. Which would obviously break other libraries but it lets us know that library will actually run.

And it never hurts to check permissions.

> Am I even using these terminal commands correctly?

Yes. I tested with a fresh install of Mojave. I ran `gcc -ljpeg` and got the same error as you. Then I ran `brew install jpeg` and then `gcc -ljpeg` returns what you would expect (`undefined symbols [...] "_main"`)

In some cases the headers are bundled separately and you'll install something like `brew install package-dev` but they're bundled with the `jpeg` package.

Since you're new to MacOS, I frequently run into quirks using it for development. It's nowhere near the frustration of developing on Windows but the best way to utilize MacOS for development is to ssh into a Linux box imo

Comment: It seems like my path /usr/local/ is empty, so it doesn't contain a "Cellar" subdirectory

Comment: I looked closer at the output of your initial question, brew is installing to /opt/homebrew so you must have an ARM processor Mac. Check the /opt/homebrew directory for the jpeg package and run `brew link jpeg` to trigger the linking to /usr/local if it exists. See if that flags an error. And if you haven't already ran `brew doctor` start with that

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, adding the path to the jpeg library will work but homebrew should be automatically linking to the existing library. If you fix it with homebrew you likely won't have to do this with every library you install which could quickly become unwieldy. If only the jpeg package is affected then imo the better fix would be to create symlinks, `ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jpeg/9d/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib /usr/local/lib; ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jpeg/9d/lib/libjpeg.9.a /usr/local/lib; ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jpeg/9d/lib/libjpeg.dylib /usr/local/lib;`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find the installation path by trying to uninstall the library.

I ran "brew uninstall jpeg", and it refused to install because of dependencies, but the first line of the error message gave me the path to look in.

```
Error: Refusing to uninstall /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jpeg/9d
```

Since I'm using this library for an Xcode project, I just had to add this path + /lib/ to my library search paths in Xcode, and it was able to find the library.

Answer (score 1):

Using cmake and this command helped me:

```
cmake -DJPEG_LIBRARY_RELEASE=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jpeg/9e/lib/libjpeg.a
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the response.. Sadly that specific suggestion made no difference..

However I did some playing and I did get it to work by forcing the AC_CHECK_HEADERS checks to "yes" for jpeg and libmicrohttpd

```
AC_CHECK_HEADERS(setjmp.h jerror.h jpeglib.h,[JPGS="yes"],[JPGS="yes"])
```

and

```
AC_CHECK_HEADERS(microhttpd.h,[MHTTP="yes"],[MHTTP="yes"])
```

The configure was successful and motion has compiled by overriding the checks to force them to succeed.

It appears that the AC_CHECK_HEADERS on macOS 12.4 M1 is broken.